# Como inserir valores em um array vazio?

Tags: javascript, array

por exemplo : var arr = [] . Como inserir elementos dentro desse array vazio? Tentei de inúmeras formas mais sem sucesso. Tentei fazer isso de forma dinâmica mais sem sucesso.

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Edite a sua resposta adicionando um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável.

Comment: Basicamente. Como adicionar valores em um array vazio por meio de loops

Answer (score 3):

Olá,

Há diversas maneiras de fazer isso no JavaScript.

Você pode utilizar o método `push`, que adiciona elementos no final de seu vetor.

Assim:

`arr.push(1);` ou `arr.push({ nome: 'Lucas', sobrenome: 'Bittencourt' });` (contrário do método `pop`, que remove elementos do final de seu vetor)

Ou você pode utilizar o método `unshift` que adiciona elementos no começo de seu vetor.

Assim:

`arr.unshift(1);` ou `arr.unshift({ nome: 'Lucas', sobrenome: 'Bittencourt' });` (contrário do método `shift`, que remove elementos do começo de seu vetor)

Ou você pode fazer isso:

```
const arr = []

arr[arr.length] = 1;
arr[arr.length] = 2;
```

Isso resultará em [1, 2]

Ou você pode usar os métodos `splice` ou `concat`. Enfim, há muitas possibilidades :)

Comment: Valeu cara. Eu conheço esse método(push) mais isso nem passou pela minha cabeça.